# itext htmlworker not working for Myanmar character

Tags: itext

I am trying to use HTMLWorker for itext pdf and for Myanmar characters its not working, whereas in plain html it works
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://mmwebfonts.comquas.com/fonts/?font=myanmar3' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://mmwebfonts.comquas.com/fonts/?font=zawgyi' />  
    <style type="text/css">
        .zawgyi{
            font-family:Zawgyi-One;
        }
        .unicode{
            font-family:Myanmar3,Yunghkio,'Masterpiece Uni Sans';
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>This is for ZawGyI font</h3>
    <p class="zawgyi">၀န္ထမ္းလစာေပးေခ်လႊာ( လစာငွေ )
        သည္စာသည္ ေဇာ္ဂ်ီ ျဖင့္ေရးေသာစာျဖစ္သည္
    </p>
    <h3>This is for unicode (myanmar3) font</h3>
    <p class="unicode">၀န္ထမ္းလစာေပးေခ်လႊာ( လစာငွေ )
        သည်စာသည် unicode ဖြင့်ရေးသောစာဖြစ်သည်
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

itext code:

```
String str1="<html><head>\n" +
"   <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n" +
"   <title>Document</title>\n" +
"   <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href='https://mmwebfonts.comquas.com/fonts/?font=myanmar3' />\n" +
"   <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href='https://mmwebfonts.comquas.com/fonts/?font=zawgyi' />    \n" +
"   <style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
"       .zawgyi{\n" +
"           font-family:Zawgyi-One;\n" +
"       }\n" +
"       .unicode{\n" +
"           font-family:Myanmar3,Yunghkio,'Masterpiece Uni Sans';\n" +
"       }\n" +
"   </style>\n" +
"</head>\n" +
"<body>\n" +
"   <h3>This is for ZawGyI font</h3>\n" +
"   <p class=\"zawgyi\">\n" +
"       သည္စာသည္ ေဇာ္ဂ်ီ ျဖင့္ေရးေသာစာျဖစ္သည္\n" +
"   </p>\n" +
"   <h3>This is for unicode (myanmar3) font</h3>\n" +
"   <p class=\"unicode\">\n" +
"       သည်စာသည် unicode ဖြင့်ရေးသောစာဖြစ်သည်\n" +
"   </p>\n" +
"</body>\n" +
"</html>";

HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
worker.parse(new StringReader(str1));

    document.close();
```

When I tried XMLWorker then it says head tag cannot be nested.
When I use FontSelector then it works fine, but I need to parse html and not able to use FontSelector with HTML.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be an issue with iText5, I upgraded it to iText7 and now its working fine with below code:

```
File pdfDest = new File(pdfFile);
         String html = <>html;
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(true, false, true);
        converterProperties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
        try {
            HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(html,
                    new FileOutputStream(pdfDest), converterProperties);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
        }
```